# ReactJS can't import 'react-router-dom' anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

A few days ago I just worked fine on my website, and could use the following syntax: 
'import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";' 
in my program.
But today, when I wanted to go on with programming my website I got the following errors in console: `https://pastebin.com/FXqKAyzd`

---

This is odd tho because it worked just fine a few days ago. So I thought, maybe there was an update, and I updated 'react-router' and 'react-router-dom' to the newest version (at the time being: '5.0.0'). I hope someone can tell me, how to fix this, and why it says `import Router from "react-router/es/undefined"` <- `undefined`? and what `the support for the latter` is?

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where you are importing the BrowserRouter?

Comment: Kindly add code where you are using the import statement.

Comment: try removing node modules and package-lock.json and npm install again.

Comment: @Tom `import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import $ from 'jquery';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just fixed the problem. Or better said: My Laptop did. I pulled the lasted changes on my Laptop, executed "npm install" and it added one line of code to the package-lock.json

```
"minimatch": {
  "version": "3.0.4",
  "bundled": true,
  "optional": true, //this one here
  "requires": {
  "brace-expansion": "^1.1.7"
}
```

Then I pushed it, pulled it on the PC again, and voila, it worked again.
This confuses me a little bit, but ok. BTW: I tried that because of @Vikas Singh many thx!